# Possible Synthesis of MVK from 2-Butanone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, teaching-lab

My professor wanted me to set up a lab to synthesize Methyl Vinyl Ketone (AKA Butenone) from some MEK we have lying around (2-Butanone).

Now, I know there are multiple ways to do this, but the tricky part is finding out a safe way to go about this as MVK has a very low flashpoint.

[image]

I figured we could do an **acid catalyzed** alpha halogenation with *Bromine* and some *Acetic Acid*, and then follow up with an Elimation using a bulky base such as *tert-butoxide*.

The only problem is I have no idea how long, how much, or how cold/warm these materials need to be for the reaction to occur.  Ideally the entire reaction would take place in an ice water bath due to the danger, but at the same time I don't want to take five hours synthesizing one compound.

Let me know what you think, and feel free to recommend a different (but safe) route of synthesis, as our lab has plenty of chemicals to work with.  By the way, we only need to create about **10-20ml** of the stuff, but more is better.

Comment: The safest way is just to buy it. ~$120 for 100 mL.

Comment: Btw, welcome to chemistry.SE! And yeah, I don't have much insight into the topic, but I think I agree with Jerepierre. Purchasing is indeed safer than synthesizing, and probably cheaper.

Comment: Ha! Yeah that's the thing, our current supplier cannot get us the stuff until May, and we kind of need it right now.  So ideally we could make it in lab this week.

Comment: It can never be made "safe", as methyl vinyl ketone is itself extremely toxic.

Comment: @user97462 - Why not look for another supplier? There are a number of ways to look for suppliers. For example, [ChemExper](http://www.chemexper.com/search/cas/78944.html) finds 103 possible suppliers in multiple countries.

Comment: I understand that, but the entire reaction would take place in a fume hood and in an ice bath.  What I want to know is if acid catalyzed alpha halogenation works at such low temperatures.

Comment: BTW, I cannot change my school supplier, they are heartset on the one they already have.

Comment: The flash point of MVK is -7 °C, that of MEK is -9 °C. Note that the flash point of diethyl ether is -45 °C. Running reactions under nitrogen or argon, using an "Intensivkühler" (combination of Liebig and Dimroth condenser) is pretty safe. As far as the toxicity of MVK is concerned: It's the same, regardless whether you synthesize or buy it! But as pointed out by jerepierre and Ben Norris, any attempt to synthesize MVK form left-overs in the lab is more like an occupational therapy and not really reasonable.

Comment: A literature method for the laboratory synthesis of MVK can be found in [White & Haward, "The preparation and polymerisation of Methyl Vinyl Ketone" (1943)][1].

The synthesis is via the acid catalyzed elimination of water from 4-hydroxy-2-butanone with conc. phosphoric acid. They synthesized the 4-hydroxy-2-butanone from acetone and paraformaldehyde polymer, but it is commercially available now. You can find extensive details of the experimental method in the text of the paper. 
 
  [1]: http://http:pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1943/jr/jr9430000025

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there is no way to make it safe, as methyl vinyl ketone itself is a very nasty compound.

I am also not an expert on organic synthesis, but I found some procedures, that might help you in adopting a synthetic route. The one you suggested might work, but be aware, that you are dealing with a methyl ketone, which can undergo the [haloform reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haloform_reaction) quite easily.

For example, in [1] they describe the bromination with bromine and absolute methanol at the methyl group for 3-methyl-2-butanone at a nice moderate temperature range 0-10 °C. The yield is 95%. But this is not what you want. Adding an acid as catalyst might work in your favour though, as after protonation the partial positive charge is better stabilised at the higher substituted carbon.

In [2] they use *N*-bromosuccinimide and aqueous hydrogen bromide to introduce the halogen in α position. They convert hexanoic acid with thionylchlorid to the acid chloride and subsequently to 2-bromohaxanoylchloride. The reaction takes place in the also quite nasty carbon tetrachloride at about 85 °C. This might also work for your system, it's a bit warmer than you expected though.

In [3] they use sulfuryl chloride in carbon tetrachloride to convert pantane-3-one to 2-chloropentane-3-one at about 45 °C with about 80% yield. How selective this will work with an asymmetric ketone is not clear.

Once you have obtained the 3-halogeno-butan-2-one, things will not get easier. I found a patent [4], where they convert 3-chlorobutan-2-one via pyrolysis with sodium acetate at 500-550 °C.

I could not find a reference for an elimination, but that should also work as long as you use a bulky base.

Wikipedia [5] has a different route for the synthesis, which might be a bit more economical and easier.

Well, good luck!

---

1. [*Org. Synth.* **1976**, *55*, 24.](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV6P0193)
2. [*Org. Synth.* **1976**, *55*, 27.](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv6p0190)
3. [*Org. Synth.* **2002**, *79*, 251.](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=V79P0251)
4. [J. R. Long: *Preparation of methyl vinyl ketone*. US 2256149 A, 16. 09. 1941.](http://www.google.com/patents/US2256149)
5. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_vinyl_ketone#Production

Comment: Haloform reactions only happen in base according to Clayden et al. OP is using a acid catalyst.

Comment: @Jori I included this as a courtesy warning. What is your suggestion to improve the answer?

Comment: Wow thanks Martin, that is a seriously good answer, thanks for the help!